# Why do they kill this character in Baby Driver?

Tags: plot-explanation, baby-driver

I want to know why do they kill JD in Baby Driver and who does it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Who does it?

We don't *see* it but the implication is that it was **Bats**.

> Why does he kill JD

Because JD has proved himself unreliable and less than smart.

..JD...

- gets the wrong masks for the robbery,
- trips over the loot when they hijack the car on the freeway and then
- leaves his shotgun behind...

In Bats' words to Baby...

> See JD over there? Now JD's an idiot

Comment: I thought the implication was that it was Doc, or at least if it was Bats, it’s because Doc told him to do it.